# CakePHP testing with assert Session value

Tags: session, cakephp, testing, assert

I have a  Controller with action book:

```
class SeatFormController extends AppController{
   public function book($layout,$tourcode,$date){
      if($tourcode){
          $this->Session->write('seatform_tourcode',$tourcode);
          .....
      }
   }
}
```

Now, I have SeatFormControllerTest class

```
class SeatFormControllerTest extends ControllerTestCase{
 public function testBook(){
  $result = $this->testAction('/tour/seat_form/book/plumeriabali/TPPTN6TM31-TPW');
 }
}
```

How I can assert value of Session variable 'seatform_tourcode'.
I tried to use `$this->controller->Session->read('seatform_tourcode')` in test but it doesn't work.
I also tried:

```
$tourcode = 'TPPTN6TM31-TPW';
$this->controller->Session->expects(
            $this->once())->method('read')
            ->with($this->equalTo('seatform_tourcode'))
            ->will($this->returnValue($tourcode));
```

But it seems doesn't return my expected.

Any advice? thank so much!

Answer (score 1):

I think we can use :

```
$this->assertEquals($_SESSION['seatform_tourcode'.$tourcode],$tourcode);
```